# Can someone explain why Perl behaves this way (variable scoping)?

Tags: perl

My test goes like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

func();
my $string = 'string';
func();

sub func {
    print $string, "\n";
}
```

And the result is:

```
Use of uninitialized value $string in print at test.pl line 10.

string
```

Perl allows us to call a function before it has been defined. However when the function uses a variable declared only after the function call, the variable appears to be undefined. Is this behavior documented somewhere? Thank you!

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: Oh ya I actually have those pragmas in my test file. I'll edit it. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

The behaviour of `my` is documented in [`perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my()) - it boils down to this - `perl` knows `$string` is in scope - because the `my` tells it so.

> The my operator declares the listed variables to be lexically confined to the enclosing block, conditional (if/unless/elsif/else), loop (for/foreach/while/until/continue), subroutine, eval, or do/require/use'd file.

It means it's 'in scope' from the point at which it's first 'seen' until the closing bracket of the current 'block'. (Or in your example - the end of the code)

However - in your example `my` *also* assigns a value.

This scoping process happens at compile time - where perl checks where it's valid to use `$string` or not. (Thanks to `strict`). However - it can't know what the value was, because that might change during code execution. (and is non-trivial to analyze)

So if you do this it might be a little clearer what's going on:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string; #undefined
func();
$string = 'string';
func();

sub func {
    print $string, "\n";
}
```

`$string` is in scope in both cases - because the `my` happened at compile time - before the subroutine has been called - but it doesn't have a value set beyond the default of `undef` prior to the first invocation.

Note this contrasts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub func {
    print $string, "\n";
}

my $string; #undefined
func();
$string = 'string';
func();
```

Which errors because when the sub is declared, `$string` isn't in scope.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I would consider this undefined behaviour since it skips executing `my` like `my $x if $cond;` does.

That said, the behaviour is currently consistent and predictable. And in this instance, it behaves *exactly* as expected if the optimization that warranted the undefined behaviour notice didn't exit.

---

At compile-time, `my` has the effect of declaring and allocating the variable<sup>[1]</sup>. Scalars are initialized to undef when created. Arrays and hashes are created empty.

`my $string` was encountered by the compiler, so the variable was created. But since you haven't executed the assignment yet, it still has its default value (undefined) during the first call to `func`.

This model allows variables to be captured by closures.

Example 1:

```
{
   my $x = "abc";
   sub foo { $x }   # Named subs capture at compile-time.
}

say foo();  # abc, even though $x fell out of scope before foo was called.
```

Example 2:

```
sub make_closure {
   my ($x) = @_;
   return sub { $x };   # Anon subs capture at run-time.
}

my $foo = make_closure("foo");
my $bar = make_closure("bar");

say $foo->();  # foo
say $bar->();  # bar
```

---

1. The allocation is possibly deferred until the variable is actually used.

Comment: I don't follow. Running `perl -MDevel::Peek -e'mysub(); my $foo; sub mysub { Dump($foo) }'` shows `$foo` with the PADMY flag, while `perl -MDevel::Peek -e'mysub(); sub mysub { Dump($foo) }'` (obviously) doesn't. I don't know much about perlguts, so I could be way off, but it seems like `my` isn't being skipped. Could you explain more?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, It's undefined behaviour to use a lexical varaible before EXECUTING the `my` that declares it*.  Its EXECUTION came after the first call to `func()` in the OP's code. Therefore, his program relies on undefined behaviour. You merely showed that `my` has a compile-time effect, as I stated. (* These aren't the words used by the docs. This is my understanding of the unclear docs.)